# Download file from URL and place it in Resource folder in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsurl, resourcebundle, nsbundle

I am new to iPhone developer,

How can i download the epub file from `url` and store it in Resource folder ?

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    fileData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sample%20epub%20filetype%3Aepub&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub&ei=i5gHUIOWJI3RrQeGro3YAg&usg=AFQjCNFPKsV-tieF4vKv7BXYmS-QEvd7Uw"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.fileData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.fileData appendData:data];        
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]];

    if ([self.fileData writeToFile:path options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile error");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Written!");
    }
}
```

I am not able to see anything in my `NSLog`.

Comment: please provide more information like... R u getting anything in receivedData? please Enable Zombie from arguments it will give you more information about crash

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of `connectionDidFinishLoading:`and see where it crashes?

Comment: my application is not getting crashed, see my EDIT, i kept breakpoint over `connectionDidFinishLoading:` but it is not getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in creation of file path also while writing. you have not specified any filename in the path. In the below line, I have used file name as "filename.txt". Give some proper name and it will write.

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/filename.txt", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

There is a problem in creating URL also. Do it like this,

```
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sample%20epub%20filetype%3Aepub&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub&ei=i5gHUIOWJI3RrQeGro3YAg&usg=AFQjCNFPKsV-tieF4vKv7BXYmS-QEvd7Uw"];
     NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];
```

You have created your file data with below line.

```
fileData = [NSMutableData data];
```

Make it like below,

```
fileData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
```

OR

```
self.fileData = [NSMutableData data];
```

Here iOS releases filedata before your connection delegate get called.

Comment: I tried your ans, it is not working, i Implemented `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction %@",error);    
}` my log shows `bad url`

Comment: See edited answer. You should create URL with stringWithString and not with string WithFormat.

Comment: now delegates are getting called and i can see my log results, it is showing `writeToFile error`

Comment: Dude i am confused when i used this url `http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt` and when i write this,`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/abc.txt", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    
    if ([self.fileData writeToFile:path options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile error"); }
    else {
 NSLog(@"Written!");
    }
}`

Comment: then i am able to see abc.txt file with content. **actually what i want is,** download .epub file from url and place it in iPhone simulator path.

Comment: You cant store it outside application. you must store it in document directory only.

Comment: how to Store it in document directory ? But can i fetch file from Web and store it in my Simulator memory ?

Comment: It is already storing it in document directory. See the path it prints using NSLog. It will be like NSLog(@"%@",path).

Comment: my log shows `/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/FC1C4EB5-4E35-4320-B685-9F840ED1F122/Documents` is it my document directory path ?

Comment: ya i am able to see my `abc.txt` file but i am unable to see my epub file which i have downloaded from this url: `http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sample%20epub%20filetype%3Aepub&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub&ei=i5gHUIOWJI3RrQeGro3YAg&usg=AFQjCNFPKsV-tieF4vKv7BXYmS-QEvd7Uw`

Comment: in the path change the name with abc.epub.

Comment: dude your logic is correct and i am able to see my `.epub` file in my document directory but what if user download 2 or more epub simultaneously ?

Comment: you should change your filename each time when user downloads new file.